# Problems including server components when bundling design system libraries

Tags: reactjs, vite, bundle, react-server-components

I'm using tailwindcss with react to create a design system.
Previously, I had no problem importing from server components,
but I've encountered a problem when the design system includes external libraries that are client-only.

Previously used without issue in server components, the

```
type jsx
import { Icon } from '@design/my-design-system';
import { Metadata } from 'next';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'EGRIT / 공지사항',
};

async function NoticePage() {
  // const a = systemColorToken.text['500'];
  return <Icon.Link />;
}

export default NoticePage;
```

Installed and bundled the external library 'antd', which requires 'client use' in the design system, and deployed the package.

```
type ㅓsx
import { Icon } from '@design/my-design-system';
import { Metadata } from 'next';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'EGRIT / 공지사항',
};

async function NoticePage() {
  // const a = systemColorToken.text['500'];
  return <Icon.Link />;
}

export default NoticePage;
```

The corresponding 'Icon.Button' was also available in the existing server component in the design system.

However, I get an error as shown in the picture below.
The bundler is using 'vite'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM1bR.png)

Which method should I use when bundling?
I am currently using the following method for 'index.ts'.

```
type ts
/* Icon */
export { Icon } from './icons/icon.ts';
export { getIconComponent, iconNames } from './icons/icon-utils.ts';
export type { IconNameType } from './icons/icon-utils.ts';

/* BaseModal */
export { BaseModal, type BaseModalProps } from './stories/modal/BaseModal.tsx';

/* Select */
export { Select, type SelectProps, type OptionType } from './stories/forms/select/Select.tsx';

/* BadgeDot */
export { BadgeDot, type BadgeDotType } from './stories/badges/BadgeDot.tsx';

/* Checkbox */
export { Checkbox, type CheckboxProps } from './stories/forms/checkbox/Checkbox.tsx';

/* -------------------- @client component@ --------------- */

/* DateRangePicker */
/* DatePicker */
export { DatePicker, type DatePickerProps } from './stories/forms/picker/DatePicker.tsx';

export {
  DateRangePicker,
  type DateRangePickerProps,
} from './stories/forms/picker/DateRangePicker.tsx';

/* Input */
export { Input, type InputProps } from './stories/forms/input/Input.tsx';

/* Textarea */
export { Textarea, type TextareaProps } from './stories/forms/textarea/Textarea.tsx';
```

I would be really grateful if you could let me know!!